# Jackson object mapper correctly decoding JSON when used standalone but failing when set as Webclient component

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

In my Kotlin/Spring Boot web application I am customising my WebClient by doing the following:

```
private val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

val strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs {
    it.defaultCodecs()
        .jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2JsonDecoder(mapper))
    it.defaultCodecs()
        .jackson2JsonEncoder(Jackson2JsonEncoder(mapper))
}.build()

val client = WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .build()
```

With this setup I want to be able to perform HTTP requests against an endpoint that returns the following JSON:

```
{"foo":"foo","date":"2020-11-01","bar":{"foo":"foo","bar":42}}
```

The model that I use to represent this response is the following:

```
data class FooInnerModel(val foo: String, val bar: Int)
data class FooModel(
    val foo: String,
    val date: LocalDate? = null,
    val bar: FooInnerModel
)
```

The issue that I am encountering is that the following request:

```
      client
            .get()
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(FooModel::class.java)
```

Fails with

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2020-11-01')
```

But the mapper itself, thanks to the inclusion of the JavaTimeModule seems to be capable of deserializing the JSON to the model. In fact the following line does not produce any error:

```
mapper.readValue(<copy pasted JSON from above>, FooModel::class.java)
```

I would expect the webclient to be using this same mapper in his exchange, and therefore I am not able to understand the cause of the above failure.

Comment: When you use mapper, it has already realized serlization of `LocalDate`. To achieve the same result, try to add additional annotaions to `date` val: `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy/dd/MM") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/dd/MM")`